# Angular HTTP could not get full response

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, http

I try to get full request using http post request in angular 8. But i couid not get full respose from the front end. It is like this,

```
{"classname": "2A"}
```

But I tried to check backend using postman. It gave me correct response like below,

```
{
    "stuPosition": 2,
    "stuAverage": "80.0000",
    "classname": "2A"
}
```

This is my .ts code

```
async classStudentData() {
    const Studata = {
      term: this.DataForm1.value.term,
      classname: this.DataForm1.value.className,
      year: this.DataForm1.value.year,
      userid: this.userid
    };

    const url = 'http://localhost:3000/student_marks/studentAverage'

    this.http.post<any>(url, Studata).subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res)
    })
}
```

server.js file
I have colsole.log() stuAverage in back-end when i send my request from the front-end, it is **undifined**. But the postman request does not undifined.

```
router.post("/studentAverage", function (req, res) {
    const year = req.body.year
    const term = req.body.term
    const userid = req.body.userid
    const classname = req.body.classname
    console.log(typeof(term))
    console.log(year + " " + term + " " + userid + " " + classname);

    var stuPosition;
    var stuAverage;
    var arr1 = new Array();
    mark.aggregate([
        {
            $match: { "year": year, "term": term, "classname": classname }
        },
        {
            $unwind: "$marks"
        },
        {
            $group: {
                _id: "$marks.userid",
                avg: { $avg: { $toInt: "$marks.mark" } },
            }
        }
    ])
        .sort({ _id: 1 })
        .exec()
        .then(function (resp) {
            var i = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < resp.length; i++) {
                arr1.push(resp[i])
            }

            var j = 0
            for (j = 0; j < arr1.length; j++) {
                if (arr1[j]._id == userid) {
                    stuPosition = j + 1
                    stuAverage = Math.floor(arr1[j].avg).toFixed(4)
                }
            }
            const avg = stuAverage
            console.log(avg)
            res.send({ 
                stuPosition: stuPosition,
                stuAverage: avg,
                classname: classname
            })
        });
})
```

Comment: I can't see any obvious mistakes here. Have you tried to console.log your 'Studata' right before you do the Http request, to make sure it actually holds the values you believe it does?

Comment: Yes I have check the back-end console log. All data received correctly. @SnorreDan

Comment: What exactly is the response sent by the server (some code would be appreciated)? I mean all of it, headers, status code etc. This might be a parsing error somewhere.

Comment: Could it be that you have in postman asked for a certain Id, while in your post request you only have the base url, so it doesn't send the Id, so it just returns the classname that everyone has?

Comment: @IngeOlaisen I took this user id from the cookies. Therefore i already defined the userid in constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Here I check the back-end request values data types, They are numbers and strings, Again I check postman request, they all are String type. Therefore I convert all the values to string in the code like below.

```
    const year = req.body.year.toString()
    const term = req.body.term.toString()
    const userid = req.body.userid.toString()
    const classname = req.body.classname.toString()
```

Now code works fine. Thank all who are supporting me.